# Using figures from papers in PhD applications

Tags: phd, citations, application, statement-of-purpose

Is it okay to use figures from other papers when writing a statement of purpose for a PhD application, after of course citing the paper? Or do I have to ask for permission from the author?

Comment: It would probably be fine, but I'm not sure I would

Answer (score 1):

This would almost certainly be fair use. You aren't "publishing" by sharing with the application process. But, yes, citation is proper.

Note, however, that fair use is a variable (even non-existent) concept depending on the legal jurisdiction. If you are in a place with very strict rules you need to be a bit more careful, not that anyone is likely to object, even if they learn of it.